# How can I search for a string that may or may not be across two lines?

Tags: bash, search, grep, line, cut

So I am trying to collect as series of numbers after a string. However, the string's position in the block of text I am sorting through can change a lot.

Here is the full code I am working with right now:

```
echo name HF MP2 | cat > allE

for i in *.out
    do grep "Slide" $i | cut -d "\\" -f2 | cat | tr -d '\n' > $i.name && 
    grep "EUMP2" $i | cut -d "=" -f3 | cut -c 1-25 | tr '\n' ' ' >> $i.mp2 && 
    grep 'AG\\HF' $i | cut -d "=" -f3 | cut -c 1-13 | tr '\n' ' ' >> $i.hf && 
    paste $i.name >> $i.energies &&
    paste $i.hf >> $i.energies &&
    sed -i 's/[ABCEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]//g' $i.mp2 &&
    paste $i.mp2 >> $i.energies &&
    transpose $i.energies >> $i.allE #temp.txt &&
    #cat temp.txt > $i.energies
    #echo $i is finished
done

echo see allE for energies

rm *.energies #temp.txt
rm *.name
rm *.mp2
```

The string I am searching for is AG\HF. 
The problem is the data it is searching through can look like  (Note: there are actual new line characters in this data, which I think is causing a bit of the problem)

```
 1\1\GINC-N076\SP\RMP2-FC\CC-pVDZ\C12H12\R2536\09-Apr-2020\0\\# mp2/cc-
 pVDZ\\Squish3_Slide0\\0,1\H,0,0.,2.4822,0.\C,0,0.,1.3948,0.\C,0,0.,-1.
 3948,0.\C,0,1.2079,0.6974,0.\C,0,-1.2079,0.6974,0.\C,0,-1.2079,-0.6974
 ,0.\C,0,1.2079,-0.6974,0.\H,0,2.1497,1.2411,0.\H,0,-2.1497,1.2411,0.\H
 ,0,-2.1497,-1.2411,0.\H,0,2.1497,-1.2411,0.\H,0,0.,-2.4822,0.\C,0,0.,1
 .3948,3.\C,0,0.,-1.3948,3.\C,0,1.2079,0.6974,3.\C,0,-1.2079,0.6974,3.\
 C,0,-1.2079,-0.6974,3.\C,0,1.2079,-0.6974,3.\H,0,0.,2.4822,3.\H,0,2.14
 97,1.2411,3.\H,0,-2.1497,1.2411,3.\H,0,-2.1497,-1.2411,3.\H,0,2.1497,-
 1.2411,3.\H,0,0.,-2.4822,3.\\Version=ES64L-G09RevD.01\State=1-AG\HF=-4
 61.3998608\MP2=-463.0005321\RMSD=3.490e-09\PG=D02H [SG"(C4H4),X(C8H8)]
 \\@
```

OR

```
 1\1\GINC-N076\SP\RMP2-FC\CC-pVDZ\C12H12\R2536\09-Apr-2020\0\\# mp2/cc-
 pVDZ\\Squish3.1_Slide0\\0,1\H,0,0.,2.4822,0.\C,0,0.,1.3948,0.\C,0,0.,-
 1.3948,0.\C,0,1.2079,0.6974,0.\C,0,-1.2079,0.6974,0.\C,0,-1.2079,-0.69
 74,0.\C,0,1.2079,-0.6974,0.\H,0,2.1497,1.2411,0.\H,0,-2.1497,1.2411,0.
 \H,0,-2.1497,-1.2411,0.\H,0,2.1497,-1.2411,0.\H,0,0.,-2.4822,0.\C,0,0.
 ,1.3948,3.1\C,0,0.,-1.3948,3.1\C,0,1.2079,0.6974,3.1\C,0,-1.2079,0.697
 4,3.1\C,0,-1.2079,-0.6974,3.1\C,0,1.2079,-0.6974,3.1\H,0,0.,2.4822,3.1
 \H,0,2.1497,1.2411,3.1\H,0,-2.1497,1.2411,3.1\H,0,-2.1497,-1.2411,3.1\
 H,0,2.1497,-1.2411,3.1\H,0,0.,-2.4822,3.1\\Version=ES64L-G09RevD.01\St
 ate=1-AG\HF=-461.4104442\MP2=-463.0062587\RMSD=3.651e-09\PG=D02H [SG"(
 C4H4),X(C8H8)]\\@
```

OR

```
 1\1\GINC-N076\SP\RMP2-FC\CC-pVDZ\C12H12\R2536\09-Apr-2020\0\\# mp2/cc-
 pVDZ\\Squish3.3_Slide1.7\\0,1\H,0,0.,2.4822,0.\C,0,0.,1.3948,0.\C,0,0.
 ,-1.3948,0.\C,0,1.2079,0.6974,0.\C,0,-1.2079,0.6974,0.\C,0,-1.2079,-0.
 6974,0.\C,0,1.2079,-0.6974,0.\H,0,2.1497,1.2411,0.\H,0,-2.1497,1.2411,
 0.\H,0,-2.1497,-1.2411,0.\H,0,2.1497,-1.2411,0.\H,0,0.,-2.4822,0.\C,0,
 0.,-0.3052,3.3\C,0,0.,-3.0948,3.3\C,0,1.2079,-1.0026,3.3\C,0,-1.2079,-
 1.0026,3.3\C,0,-1.2079,-2.3974,3.3\C,0,1.2079,-2.3974,3.3\H,0,0.,0.782
 2,3.3\H,0,2.1497,-0.4589,3.3\H,0,-2.1497,-0.4589,3.3\H,0,-2.1497,-2.94
 11,3.3\H,0,2.1497,-2.9411,3.3\H,0,0.,-4.1822,3.3\\Version=ES64L-G09Rev
 D.01\State=1-AG\HF=-461.436061\MP2=-463.0177441\RMSD=7.859e-09\PG=C02H
  [SGH(C4H4),X(C8H8)]\\@
```

OR

```
 1\1\GINC-N076\SP\RMP2-FC\CC-pVDZ\C12H12\R2536\09-Apr-2020\0\\# mp2/cc-
 pVDZ\\Squish3.6_Slide0.9\\0,1\H,0,0.,2.4822,0.\C,0,0.,1.3948,0.\C,0,0.
 ,-1.3948,0.\C,0,1.2079,0.6974,0.\C,0,-1.2079,0.6974,0.\C,0,-1.2079,-0.
 6974,0.\C,0,1.2079,-0.6974,0.\H,0,2.1497,1.2411,0.\H,0,-2.1497,1.2411,
 0.\H,0,-2.1497,-1.2411,0.\H,0,2.1497,-1.2411,0.\H,0,0.,-2.4822,0.\C,0,
 0.,0.4948,3.6\C,0,0.,-2.2948,3.6\C,0,1.2079,-0.2026,3.6\C,0,-1.2079,-0
 .2026,3.6\C,0,-1.2079,-1.5974,3.6\C,0,1.2079,-1.5974,3.6\H,0,0.,1.5822
 ,3.6\H,0,2.1497,0.3411,3.6\H,0,-2.1497,0.3411,3.6\H,0,-2.1497,-2.1411,
 3.6\H,0,2.1497,-2.1411,3.6\H,0,0.,-3.3822,3.6\\Version=ES64L-G09RevD.0
 1\State=1-AG\HF=-461.4376969\MP2=-463.0163868\RMSD=7.263e-09\PG=C02H [
 SGH(C4H4),X(C8H8)]\\@
```

And several other possible combinations.
Currently I am using grep with a = as a delimiter and that works about 60% of the time.
The grep reads like so:

```
grep 'AG\\HF' $i | cut -d "=" -f3 | cut -c 1-13 | tr '\n' ' ' >> $i.hf
```

This grep is going to occur many times in the same file.

Any suggestions for making the collection of the desired 13 characters consistently would be greatly appreciated.

The end result should look like:

```
-461.4440942  -461.4441024  -461.4441114  -461.4441212  -461.4441321  -461.4441575  -461.4441725  -461.4441893  -461.444208  -461.4442289  -461.4442522  -461.444278  -461.4443063  -461.4443371  -461.4444054  -461.4444421  -461.4444798  -461.4445175  -461.4445544  -461.4445891
```

What I actually get is a combination of the desired output and this:

```
-461.4417716\ -461.4413023\ 1-AG\HF -461.439848\M -461.4387568\ -461.4373225\ -461.4354367\ -461.4329522\ -461.4296709\ -461.4253285\ -461.419576\M -461.4119582\ 1-AG\HF -461.4432257\ -461.4431843\ -461.4431419\ -461.443098\M -461.4430519\ 1-AG\HF -461.4429461\ -461.4428799\ -461.4427974\ -461.4426902\ -461.4425469\ -461.4423525\ -461.4420882\ -461.4417302\ -461.4412489\ 1-AG\HF -461.439758\M -461.4386392\ -461.4371684\ -461.4352341\ -461.4326853\ -461.4293183\ -461.4248614\ -461.4189557\ -461.411132\M 1-AG\HF -461.4432226\ -461.443181\M -461.4431381\ -461.4430938\ -461.4430472\ 1-AG\HF -461.4429401\ -461.4428728\ -461.4427889\ -461.44268\MP -461.4425343\ -461.4423369\ -461.4420684\ -461.4417048\ -461.4412162\ 1-AG\HF -461.4397026\ -461.4385667\ -461.4370734\ -461.4351091\ -461.4325204\ -461.4291001\ -461.424572\M -461.4185707\ -461.4106184\ 1-AG\HF -461.4432215\ -461.4431798\ -461.4431369\ -461.4430924\ -461.4430457\ 1-AG\HF -461.442938\M -461.4428704\ -461.4427861\ -461.4426766\ -461.4425301\ -461.4423316\ -461.4420617\ -461.4416963\ -461.4412051\ 1-AG\HF -461.4396839\ -461.4385423\ -461.4370413\ -461.4350669\ -461.4324646\ -461.4290263\ -461.4244739\ -461.4184402\ -461.4104442\ 1-AG\HF
```

Using the line

```
    awk -v ORS=' ' -F= '$3 ~ /AG\\HF$/{print substr($4, 1, 12)}' $i >> $i.hf &&
```

All that was output was

```
                     -4 -4 -4
```

Comment: Please add your expected output for each sample input.

Comment: What is your actual output? How does it differ from the expected output?

Comment: Are the records all of the same length? (i.e. is it possible to process the file in chunks of XXX characters, instead of by line). Is there always a start sentinel & end sentinel in the data?

Comment: @ScottieH They are not always the same length nor does the value of interest always occur on the same line. Now, each set of data (which is a variable number of lines long) begins with ```1\1\GINC``` and ends with ```\\@```

Comment: That's helpful. I've been out sick. Do you have an answer? Otherwise, I have an idea.

Comment: @ScottieH Yes. I've made the script go through and remove the newline characters if it is breaking up the desired text. Then I call HF as the delimiter and collect the characters.

Comment: That was my idea. Nice job!!

Answer (score 1):

You may use this single `awk`:

```
awk -F= '$3 ~ /AG\\HF$/{print substr($4, 1, 12)}' file
```

```
-461.3998608
-461.4104442
-461.4440942
-461.4441483
```

To get output in single line:

```
awk -v ORS=' ' -F= '$3 ~ /AG\\HF$/{print substr($4, 1, 12)}' file
```

Comment: What are $3 and $4 defined as? I'm not super familiar with awk.

Comment: Unfortunately, that worked even less than the original grep command I was using.

Comment: `$n` is `nth` field in awk delimited by `=`